# wijmo popup calendar

Tags: jquery, html, wijmo

Hi I'm using the wijmo popup calendar.

I've managed to automatically select the date by using

```
$("#to-calendar").wijcalendar("selectDate", "March 14, 2012");
```

The problem is that the calendar displays the current month be default. Is there anyway to automatically change the month/year view for the calendar?

I've searched the wijmo website and documentation but struggling to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah figured it out, need to also add in: displayDate:

```
$("#to-calendar").wijcalendar(
            {
                popupMode: true,
                showOtherMonthDays: false,
                displayDate: new Date('2010/08/25')

            });
```